# Why does Firebase pendingAuthResult return null?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I am trying to implement **Sign in with Apple** using Firebase Authentication. I am following the [firebase/quickstart-android](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/kotlin/GenericIdpActivity.kt) sample.

My sign-in fragment overrides `onStart()` to check for any pending results:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    val pending = auth.pendingAuthResult

    pending?.addOnSuccessListener { authResult ->
        Timber.d("Successful login, pending")
    }?.addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Timber.d("Failed login, pending")
    }
}
```

And a button that initiates the sign-in flow:

```
btnApple.onClick {
    viewModel.appleLogin(requireActivity())
}
```

The viewModel calls the following method from a repository:

```
// Initiate sign-in flow only if there are no pending results
if (auth.pendingAuthResult != null) {
    return
}

val scopes = listOf("email", "name")
val provider = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("apple.com", auth)
    .setScopes(scopes)
    .build()

auth.startActivityForSignInWithProvider(activity, provider)
    .addOnSuccessListener { authResult ->
        Timber.d("Successful login, normal")
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Timber.e(e, "Failed login, normal")
    }
```

---

The [official manual](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/apple#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk) states:

> Signing in with this method puts your Activity in the background, which means that it can be reclaimed by the system during the sign in flow.

So I started testing the pending result by terminating the app in Android Studio while completing the sign-in flow in Chrome. Once I returned back to the app, the `onStart()` was called, but the `pendingAuthResult` was always null.

To make it more interesting, when I restart the app, I am logged in. Then if I log out and enter the sign-in fragment again, there is a pending result now and I receive `Successful login, pending`. On top of that, the **pending result does not disappear**. If I leave the sign-in fragment and go back, the pending result is still there and I receive yet another `Successful login, pending`.

I even tested the [firebase/quickstart-android](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/kotlin/GenericIdpActivity.kt) sample itself and it has exactly the same issue.

What could be the possible cause of this issue? I am using `firebase-auth:19.2.0`.

Comment: Same issue here. To test this I'm using developer feature "Don't keep activities".

Comment: Did you ever solve this? The github issue is still open.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the firebase for signing with apple and if it's handled manually then you should use a string decoding mechanism, Please find the firebase guide for the same and hope it'll works. let me know if any issue!

[Firebase guild signing with apple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/apple)